# QlikView - Force table box to not show data if date range in calendar object is data empty

Tags: qlikview, qlik-expression

i have a calendar object that uses a master calendar as base. All the data is shown on a table box and this data is based on the date range selected on the calendar object.

My data does not have values for all the date range but only for some days/months.

Ex:

My master calendar goes from 01/01/2022 to 01/01/2024 but i only have data for some months and days of this range. The reason why this calendar goes from 01/01/2022 to 01/01/2024 is that the "MinDate" on dataset is 01/01/2022 and the "MaxDate" on dataset is 01/01/2024.

i know that qlikview logic is to show all the data if there is no data in that date range, but i need the opposite. I want to show no data in my table box if there is no data in the date range.

is that possible?

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object type will decide how you do this.

If is a table object: (I think this is your option)
You choose the column that you want to control the show hide option and then turn the Omit rows option on

[image]

If it is a straight table chart type and you want a dimension to control the show hide of the row

[image]

And lastly if it is an expression that will determine the show hide then the option is here

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! Worked as i expected!! Thank you so much!!